# Perl Term::ReadLine stdin issue

Tags: perl, ssh

So I have a Term::Readline loop that executes code via ssh however that code uses  which makes Term::Readline not be happy.

How do I pause Term::Readline from reading STDIN and allow STDIN to work as normal on my external script?

Some example code:

```
ssh root@server "perl <<'EOF'
use strict;
chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
print $answer;
EOF
```

Please note that this ssh is being called from within the Term::ReadLine loop.

Comment: You are attaching the heredoc data to the remote perl STDIN channel and discarding the former STDIN that's coming there through the SSH channel.